# NodeJS Program wont run

Tags: javascript, node.js

so I am having issues trying to run a program with Node that I have made in javascript im not sure what is wrong and I cant really found out either because it provides no stack or error and just simply ends

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')()
const exit = require('exit')()
const wait = require('wait')
var loop = 0


while (loop == 0) {
    var clean_combine = prompt("are you cleaning or combining files, or both? ")
    var clean_combine = clean_combine.toLowerCase()
    if (clean_combine == "cleaning") {
        console.log("starting cleaner")
        require('child_process').exec('node cleaner.js')
        wait(7500)
        console.log("ending process")
        exit
    }
    if (clean_combine == "both") {
        console.log("starting cleaner")
        require('child_process').exec('node cleaner.js')
        console.log("waiting to start combiner")
        wait(30000)
        console.log("starting combiner")
        require('child_process').exec('node combiner.js')
        wait(7500)
        console.log("ending process")
        exit
    }
    if (clean_combine == "combining") {
        console.log("starting combiner")
        require('child_process').exec('node combiner.js')
        wait(7500)
        console.log("ending process")
        exit
    }
    else {console.log("error invalid syntax")}
}
```

Comment: Just began looking at your code and immediately, I see that `var clean_combine = clean_combine.toLowerCase` is wrong.  It should be `var clean_combine = clean_combine.toLowerCase()`.  FYI, relevant code is supposed to be posted into the question itself here, not available only as a link to an external resource.  This is because that external resource will change tomorrow, rendering the question useless as a longer term reference for others.

Comment: And, what is `exit` all by itself?  That won't accomplish anything.  Perhaps you meant for it to be `exit()`.

Comment: And, since `loop` is NEVER `==1`, your code never executes anything inside the loop.

Comment: Please do not post a link to your code repository-- once you update it, the question will lose value for others because the initial conditions of the question will be missing.  Instead, include the code as a [mcve] in the body of the question.

Comment: And, you could figure this out yourself by learning how to run the nodejs debugger and then step through your code line by line.  You would quickly find that it gets to `while (loop == 1)` and never goes into that loop to execute anything else.  It is worth learning how to run the debugger.  You NEED debugging tools to help you solve problems in your code.

Comment: FYI, I'm not really seeing anything in your nodejs program that can't be done purely from a batch file.

Comment: it makes it easier to see syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not crashing. It's exiting without issue. You initialize loop to 0 and then start an infinite loop while loop is 1 but it's never 1 so it just exits.

Change it from loop=0 to loop=1

Comment: Better yet, use a Boolean or just do `while(true)` since the loop is supposed to be terminated by a call to `exit()`.

Comment: oversight on my part, after staring at the code for a little while you dont catch such things